# Has_many for different classes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, has-many, has-many-through, has-many-polymorphs

Here is the thing.

I'm working on a web game just for learning and I have this problem.

I have a Character who has many items, but the items can be equipable_items or usable_items (both from different clases).

Is there a way to have a has_many in my Character class to have a bag of items of both clases together?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, check out [Single Table Inheritance](http://railsforum.com/viewtopic.php?id=3815).  You can do a has_many association to the parent class.

EDIT: Also check out the Single Table Inheritance section in the [API documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html).

Comment: both classes are very diferent. Isn't better to use multi-table Inheritance?

Comment: It depends on how and in what ways they are different.  If they have completely different attributes in the database then it may be better to use MTI (I would still stick to STI though if the number of differing attributes is low).  If it's only the behavior that's different, then STI is the right solution, since behavior is defined by how you write the classes rather than by their tables.

Rails readily supports STI so I tend to prefer it unless it's completely not applicable for the situation.  If you go with MTI though, you typically will need to roll your own support, which is not easy.